# document is not defined when assigning event handlers

Tags: javascript, electron

So what I'm trying to do here is bind onclick events for each of my titlebar buttons (minimize, maximize, close). When I run npm start I keep getting back "document is undefined" and I'm not really sure why. I'm pretty new to electron so and I don't really have a ton of experience with Node either, so this all seems kind of weird. I've seen a couple others asking similar questions, but none of their fixes seem to work for me.

I read somewhere that app.on('ready) doesn't mean that my DOM is necessarily loaded when dealing with electron. I'm hoping that if this in fact the case someone can explain how to handle accessing this situation. As I understand things, my current code should only bind event handlers to these buttons once my DOM is loaded, and yet 'document' still isn't recognized.

I have also not ruled out that my problem isn't completely unrelated to what I've just described. This is all quite new to me, and the frustration is mounting. In chrome something like this would be relatively benign and easy to implement, but here it seems there's a bit more to it.

Here is my Javascript:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const remote = require('electron').remote
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

var MainWindow;
app.on('ready', function() {
  MainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    backgroundColor: '123355',
    frame: false,
    resizable: true,
    movable: true,
    show: false
  })

  MainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    MainWindow.show()
    console.log('Ready to go!')
  })

  MainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true

  }))

  document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      init();
    }
  };
});

function init() {
  document.getElementById("minbtn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    window.minimize();
  });

  document.getElementById("maxbtn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    window.maximize();
  });

  document.getElementById("closebtn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    window.close();
  });
};
```

Comment: You aren't running in the page context.  You need to get the `document` from the window.

Comment: Your almost identical question got an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51521488/2550156 This is the same misconception of electron Processes